# subtract date+hour and give results in hours

Tags: excel, vba

How can I subtract below dates to each other and provide out put in hours?
Please note that the hours is a number, not a date. So I might also need some formula to change it to date. 
I plan use such code in VBA

Many thanks for helping me out.

```
date_converted
2015-06-02 14:41
2015-06-02 11:24
2015-06-03 09:35
2015-06-03 09:34
```

Answer (score 0):

```
02/06/2015 14:41    
02/06/2015 11:24    -3.283333333
03/06/2015 09:35    22.18333333
03/06/2015 09:34    -0.016666667
```

Column A and B above 
where

```
B2 = "=(A2-A1)*24" and 
B3 = "=(A3-A2)*24" and 
B4 = "=(A4-A3)*24"
```

Answer (score 0):

`=DateValue` will convert the test to an excel date value, then you can use your usual excel functions on the dates.

If you are interested in hours (and it doesn't go above 9999 hours, or negative) then you can format the cell as `[h]:mm`, or you can multiply the resulting number by 24 to get decimal hours.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code for ya.

It looks at the value in Column A/1 and copies that as a date to Col B/2, and then in Column C/3 it subtracts the previous row from the current row, only if not in row 1.
It runs through all active rows.

in cells(x,y), change the y if the column numbers change.

```
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    a = Format(Cells(i, 1).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn")
    Cells(i, 2).Value = a
    If i <> 1 Then
        Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]-R[-1]C[-1])*24"
    End If
Next i
```

So final results look like this:

`2015-06-02 14:41   6/2/2015 14:41 
2015-06-02 11:24    6/2/2015 11:24  -3.283333333
2015-06-03 09:35    6/3/2015 9:35   22.18333333
2015-06-03 09:34    6/3/2015 9:34   -0.016666667`